# Swift: UIImageView behaves strange on iPad, but perfectly fine on iPhone - how to make an image fill the view?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, aspect-ratio

Maybe this is something very easy or I do not understand the way the imageView is working, but when I place an imageView in storyboard with some constraint (see below), it displays the image the user chooses the way I want it to be displayed: filling the whole imageView (cutting of the top and bottom of the image).

When I run the same universal app on iPad (Air, Pro, ...) the imageView itself is displayed correctly (1:1) and the user can choose an image, but instead of filling the whole view, the image is displayed as a whole (with top/bottom black bars for landscape or right/left black bars for portrait photos). Is there a way to tell the app to "always" display the image filling the whole view and cutting of the rest?

This is how I set up the imageView in storyboard and code:

Storyboard:

In storyboard the imageView is placed right in the middle hugging leading and trailing sides. The aspect ratio is set to 1:1 - so it is a perfect rectangle (on iPhone 8 for instance it's 375x375) and on all simulators it stays a perfect rectangle. The content made is set to "Aspect Fit".

Code:

In code I add a tapGestureRecognizer and UIImagePickerController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    addPhotoGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.importPhoto))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(addPhotoGesture)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        // get image
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage else {return}

        // save in imageView
        imageView.image = image

        addPhotoGesture.isEnabled = false

    }
```

Again on all iPhone models the image fills the whole imageView (some parts are cut off, but that is ok). On iPad apparently the screen real estate is so big that all images are displayed completely with black bars, but I'd like to be able to have it fill the imageView, cutting of anything outside.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the content mode of your image view set to?  It sounds like you want "aspect fill".

Comment: It's aspect fit - which is alright. I thought about aspect fill at first as well, but the images are still displayed on iPad with black bars, the imageView is not "filled" so to speak. The aspect ration of the imageView constraint is 1:1

Comment: aspect fit will fit the entire image on the screen, maintaining the aspect ratio.  If the image dimensions do not match the screen dimensions then space will be added to either the top/bottom or left/right as required.  aspect fill ensures that the entire image view is filled while maintaining the aspect ratio.  If the image dimensions do not match the screen dimensions then part of the image will be offscreen as required to fill the image.  From the description of your desired behaviour you want aspect fill.

Comment: You are right, but for some reason the whole imageView is stretched on iPad instead of maintaining an 1:1 ratio it has on iPhone. What can I do about that? I think that is the reason why I decided to use aspect fit (which worked well on iPhones). Height/Width is set to 375, leading/trailing to superview is -16, 1:1 ratio to image view, align to top safe area is 60.

Comment: You shouldn't set width and leading/trailing.  You can set leading/trailing and no width **or** set width and leading (or trailing).  If you set width and leading and trailing then you are probably getting a warning about conflicting constraints since auto layout will not be able to satisfy all of those constraints at the same time.